# Selenium WebDriver PageFactory FindsBy Using jQuery Selector?

Tags: jquery-selectors, attributes, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

To explain my question, I have given a small scenario:

Say I have a login page.

```
public class LoginPage
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "SomeReallyLongIdBecauseOfAspNetControlsAndPanels_username"]
    public IWebElement UsernameField { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "SomeReallyLongIdBecauseOfAspNetControlsAndPanels_password"]
    public IWebElement PasswordField { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "submitButtonId")]
    public IWebElement SubmitButton { get; set; }

    private readonly IWebDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;

        if(!driver.Url.Contains("Login.aspx"))
        {
            throw new NotFoundException("This is not the login page.");
        }
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }

    public HomePage Login(Credentials cred)
    {

       UsernameField.sendKeys(cred.Username);
       PasswordField.SendKeys(cred.Password);
       SubmitButton.Click();

       return new HomePage(driver);
    }

}

[TestFixture]
public class Test : TestBase
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {

       driver = StartDriver(); // some function which returns my driver in a wrapped event or something so I can log everything it does.
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        new LoginPage(driver)
                .Login(new Credentials 
                           { Username = "username", 
                             Password = "password" })
                .SomeHomePageFunction()

    }
```

Eventually, I know the page configuration will change, the id's will mostly stay the same, but things are changing rapidly on my projects. I know xPath is another alternative, but due to how the pages are generated based on certain critera, this will still become painful as the path will not always be the same.

With the current code above, the page is loaded and the PageFactory init's the elements through the Page Constructor. All great. This is what I use at the moment.

Currently, if some things are not always generated on the page until a certain step. I usually do the following:

```
private const string ThisIsTheUserNameFieldId = "usernamefield";
```

Then hit up the webdriver using the following:

```
// Navigate to login page

// code here

// Enter in credentials

driver.FindElement(By.Id(ThisIsTheUserNameFieldId)).SendKeys(cred.Username);
```

Not as well structured as the PageFactory, but it's certainly a requirement which I am not able to get around.

I have recently come across some jQuery Selector code to use with C#.Net which extends the functionality of the RemoteWebDriver where I can use jQuery selectors to find my Elements on the page.

[Selenium jQuery for C#.Net (Including Source)](http://www.vcskicks.com/selenium-jquery.php)

```
// So I can do things like this:
driver.FindElement(By.jQuery("a").Find(":contains('Home')").Next())
```

**Does anyone know how I can extend the [FindsBy] Attribute in Selenium WebDriver so that it's possible to use something like the following (pseudo code)?**

```
[FindsBy(How = How.jQuery, Using = "div[id$='txtUserName']")]
public IWebElement UsernameField { get; set; }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that XPath is pretty powerful, you could easily transform div[id$='txtUserName'] to //div[ends-with(@id, 'txtUserName')]

Comment: I could of sworn I had tried this approach. I made a quick Unit Test.

OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //input[ends-with(@id, 'txtUserName')] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
[InvalidSelectorError] Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[ends-with(@id, 'txtUserName')] because of the following error:
[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "51" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR)"  location: "resource://fxdriver/modules/atoms.js Line: 2394"]

Comment: It's a shame, because I have several important web elements on several pages which are all used ALOT during each process of the steps involved in the websites use.

I have also tried using a Firefox plugin which helped identify xPath expressions and even those seemed to be invalid by Selenium. However I do think the plugin is quite old but it still stands. Its messy until it works which is great, but then I always seem to fall into this issues with XPath.

Comment: That is a shame, I would have expected WebDriver to be able to handle XPath functions... I guess you'll need something like what I posted below.

Comment: Turns out it's part of xPath 2 which isn't even supported by the new Selenium 2 WebDriver...well that sucks.

Comment: I know for a fact that it supports contains(), I suppose you could try that, although it may not be specific enough for your needs: //div[contains(@id, 'txtUserName')]

Comment: contains works perfect, though my only worry is if its like you say, specific enough. 

Have you seen the fantastic documentation they provided? 

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.html :/

Comment: lol, yeah, the documentation is practically non-existent.

Comment: Apparently its delegated down to the browser. Does this mean its a bug in Firefox as to why I can not get the ends-with function in XPath to work? I raised an issue on the Selenium google code site. They said it's not a selenium issue. so now im confused.

Comment: Looks like they use the native XPath engine if it's available, so in this case it would have to be a Firefox bug if it's not working.  You can inject a custom XPath implementation using the same method I outlined below, you could try the http://code.google.com/p/ajaxslt/source/browse/trunk/xpath.js implementation, it appears to support the latest XPath specs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't extend **[FindsBy]**, but did you know you can use elements returned by javascript?:

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver { Url = "http://www.google.com" };
var element = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.getElementsByName('q')[0];");
element.SendKeys("hello world");
```

You could easily extend this to allow for jquery selectors by first injecting jquery (taken from [JQuerify](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet) and modified):

```
const string js =
     @"{var b=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; if(typeof jQuery=='undefined'){var script=document" +
     @".createElement('script'); script.src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js';var head=document" +
     @".getElementsByTagName('head')[0],done=false;script.onload=script.onreadystatechange=function(){if(!" +
     @"done&&(!this.readyState||this.readyState=='loaded'||this.readyState=='complete')){done=true;script." +
     @"onload=script.onreadystatechange=null;head.removeChild(script);}};head.appendChild(script);}}";
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(js);
```

And then running javascript to select the element you want:

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver { Url = "http://www.google.com" };
var element = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(@"return $('input[name*=""q""]')[0];");
element.SendKeys("hello world");
```

Comment: I wish I could go with this approach, I really do. I deal with ASP.Net and most of the id's will change once a few setting changes have been made. Im trying to move towards the xPath resolution if I can, because all of this jQuery addition and javascript execution is just going to be too much to maintain and handle for fast moving projects in development stage.

Comment: That's too bad... I guess you could submit a feature request to either upgrade to XPath 2.0, or allow for JQuery selectors.

Comment: This may or may not work for you, but you could grab the Webinator project: http://webinator.codeplex.com/.  It's a project in pre-alpha (although the WebDriver portion is fully functional), and I would be happy to add JQuery support to it.

Comment: I guess this will have to do :)

Comment: FYI this answer describes exactly that the article posted by the OP does

Comment: You're right, I hadn't noticed that.  I think the article does a better job integrating By.Jquery() so it's a native call, but they don't explain how to inject jquery into a page (not that it's hard to do).  Can't believe I missed that...